# Starting a user defined service in windows Xp

Tags: windows-services, batch-file, windows-xp, user-defined

I am creating a user defined service on Windows Xp using sc.exe
To create I started with

```
sc.exe create "My Service" binPath= "D:\Service.bat"
```

Got a message  CreateService SUCCESS.

Then I entered services.msc in the RUN and found the service which I created was there

Right clicked My Service then properties and when I started

I get an error as

ERROR 1053: The service did not respond to the start in a timely fashion

How do I fix this error.

Thanks

Comment: It could be a problem, that you try to add a batch file as a service. I suppose this isn't possible

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to enter cmd as command;

```
sc.exe create "My Service" binPath= "cmd /c D:\Service.bat"
```

And make sure the batch file does not stop too quick. At the first line of the batchfile let it write to a logfile, so you can see it is being executed. (and use a location where the service user may write to).

```
echo starting at %date% %time% > d:\service.log
```

As an alternative you can also use srvany.exe, see [KB137890](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137890), but that is more hassle.